# Join tables when column name is a row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, join

I run a query like this:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
        ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       (c.name='loaddate')
and (t.name like '%_agent%')
ORDER BY    TableName
        ,ColumnName;
```

which returns: something like this:

```
columnname|TableName
loaddate| gov_agent
loaddate| fin_agent
loaddate| sav_agent
```

Within those tables, exists the date under the loaddate column. For example, gov_agent might look like this:

```
  loaddate|entity|category
2018-06-01|James |A
2018-06-01|Jim   |B
2018-05-30|Bob   |B
2018-05-29|Kevin |C
```

What I need to return, is the max value of the date listed in each table so that my results would look like this

```
loaddate| gov_agent|2018-06-01
loaddate| fin_agent|2018-06-01
loaddate| sav_agent|2018-03-02
```

I am not aware of any easy way to join these tables in order to return the max date or if this is even possible. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I can't test this for your data, however, I did alter it for a table structure on my database, and this worked. If it doesn't work, you have your best friend to help you.

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT' + STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +
                                      N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],N'''') + N' AS ColumnName,' + NCHAR(10) +
                                      N'       ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],N'''') + N' AS TableName,' + NCHAR(10) +
                                      N'       (SELECT MAX(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N') FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N') AS MaxLoadDate'
                               FROM sys.columns c
                                    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                               WHERE c.[name] ='loaddate'
                                 AND t.name LIKE '%[_]agent%' --I assumed that the understore is not meant to be a wildcard
                               FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,17,N'');
PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```